# Line breaks removal in R

Tags: r, string, line-breaks

I'm following the code of this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JyMBwydhYR8

```
All_Files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
All_opinions <- lapply(All_Files, pdf_text)

document <-  Corpus(VectorSource(All_opinions))

social_sentences <- document %>%
    tolower() %>%
    paste0(collapse= " ") %>%
    stringr::str_squish() %>%
    stringr::str_split(fixed(".")) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    tm::removePunctuation()
```

But after creating the vector 'social_sentences', the line breaks weren't removed.

Instead, after removing the punctuation, only the 'n' letter is left, which joins with the closer words.

Even in the tutorial, it is possible to see it with the word 'hilln'.

The 'str_squish()' function is already part of the code, and I even changed its place to see if it solves the problem. I also tried the 'gsub()' and 'str_replace_all()' functions.

Comment: Why are you sure that the line breaks were not removed? I have tried you code with a small sentence and no `\n` appeared. Make a compact reproducible example and show the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true, in the video extra n symbols has appeared. But in fact the code does remove `\n` completely.

Try this:

```
text <- "\n\nString with excess,  trailing and: leading! white   space\n\n"
text %>%
  tolower() %>%
  paste0(collapse= " ") %>%
  stringr::str_split(fixed(".")) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  tm::removePunctuation() %>%  
  stringr::str_squish()
```

The result is:

```
[1] "string with excess trailing and leading white space"
```

###### EDIT:

just add `str_replace_all("\\\\n", " ")` to your pipe:

```
> pdf_text("stack_1003.pdf") |>
+   VectorSource()|>
+   Corpus() |>
+   tolower() |> 
+   unlist() |>
+   paste0(collapse= " ") |>
+   str_split(fixed(".")) |>
+   str_replace_all("\\\\n", " ") |> 
+   removePunctuation() |> 
+   str_squish() 
[1] "c string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space string with excess trailing and leading white space
```

Comment: I've conducted some tests, and it appears that the error is related to the PDF format when there are more than one page.

Please, attempt to create a PDF document with more than one page by repeating this same phrase you showed me: 'String with excess, trailing and leading! white space.' There's no need to include line breaks; the result for me already included 'nstring', 'withnexcess',...